# Intellij Idea 11 fails to connect to JBoss 7.1.1 remotely

Tags: intellij-idea, jboss7.x

I am attempting to deploy a simple exploded war application from idea 11.1.3 to a remote (same machine) JBoss 7.1.1.  The War builds fine and starts to deploy, but I keep getting the following message on the attempted deploy:

> Error running JBoss 7.1.1.Final: Unable to connect to the
>   localhost:8080

I am using Intellij's default JBoss 7 Remote configuration, which I've used successfully in the past.  I can hit localhost:8080 directly with any browser so I know its responding.  Ideas?

Comment: Solved.  It turned out to be the user account the jboss process was running under (my OSX user account).  When I ran the jboss server under root, it connected every time.

Answer (score 2):

I've encountered with the same problem and found solution. May be this problem appeared because I've just switched from Eclipse. So I think someone it can be helpful.

For correct debugging JBoss remotely we need to specify 3 ports:

1) http port ('Port' field of the 'Remote Connection Settings' section) is used to ping JBoss server (periodical checking if the server is alive) and to produce urls addressing resources on the server - FIRST TAB

2) native management port ('Management port' field of the 'JBoss Server Settings' section) is used to connect to the JBoss management  interface, to check for the server startup to be finished and to deploy artifacts - FIRST TAB

3) remote socket port - by default on JBoss it 8787 - LAST TAB

After this all will work fine.

I was little bit confusing because if I run JBoss under sudo – remote debug worked just fine.